# d3.js / JSFiddle - loading .tsv data

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, jsfiddle

I created a JSfiddle to collaborate on a project but I can't get it to run properly:

- It's loading correctly the html/css elements
- It's apparently running the .js code as the dimensions  (960*500 px )of the result look correct to me

  - However it does not seem to load the dataEL.tsv file I attached as an external resource, and that I use in my code to load data via:

    ```
    window.onload = function draw(data) {           
        d3.tsv("dataEL.tsv", type, function(error, data) { 
     (...)
    ```

=> Here is the link to the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46yxnukv/2/)

Can you please help me load correctly the data in order to display the result?
It displays correctly on my **personal [server](http://simplifly.fr/Data%20Visualization/agebarchart/agebarchart.html)**

Comment: For things that require data, other sites such as http://plnkr.co/ are better.

Comment: The JSFiddle external resource option is not well documented, but it can't be used in this way.  It is *only* for extra scripts you want to load in the `<head>` of the document; inspect your result frame, and you'll see: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://simplifly.fr/Data%20Visualization/agebarchart/dataEL.tsv"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jsFiddle.net lets you upload external resources other than referencing JS files.

If you open the Javascript console, or Developer Tools of your browser (F12 assuming you are on Windows and using IE/Chrome/FF) you see that you are getting a 404 not found error for the file `dataEl.tsv`:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (NOT FOUND) http://fiddle.jshell.net/46yxnukv/2/show/dataEL.tsv

You could try a different site, or upload the file `dataEL.tsv` to an internet-accessible web server and then request it using the full URL instead of an URL on jsFiddle.net.

Comment: Thanks ! I did try replacing with full URL into the .js code for jsfiddle but did not get satisfactory results either unfortunately.